# How to include Redux Framework in Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, redux-framework

How do I include Redux Framework in Theme wordpress?

This code doesn't work:

```
<?php
  if ( !class_exists( 'ReduxFramework' ) && file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php' ) ) {
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php' );
  }
  if ( !isset( $redux_demo ) && file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/ReduxFramework/sample/sample-config.php' ) ) {
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/ReduxFramework/sample/sample-config.php' );
  }
?>
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/wiki/Embedding-Redux-into-Your-Theme-or-Plugin

Or adjust your paths correctly in the code you showed above?

Comment: Good question. It's not clearly outlined in the docs: http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

Spoiler alert, lead dev at Redux here. You could use the Redux Generator to get an admin folder and bypass some pain.

http://generate.reduxframework.com

After all, it's a free service.  :)

Comment: Redux really needs clearer documentation. They assume you know things that no person just getting starting with Redux will know. `Download just the admin folder portion. This will provide you with a folder you can place in a theme or plugin and include ~/admin/admin-init.php to initate it.` Ok, great. Now can you tell me WHERE to include admin-init.php?

Comment: Have you seen... http://docs.reduxframework.com? Probably the most complete documentation of any WordPress framework out there?  :)

Comment: @Dovy - it is indeed a great framework, and it is well documented for most parts. but a very some very important parts are missing, like for example how to [embed the framework on your own plugin](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/embed/) ( for developers) . granted - it is easy to understand - but still - for a starter developer it might help .

Comment: same problem over here. the description is just not enough for me. And when I try to open https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/embed/ i only see the message "Oops! That embed can’t be found.
It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try visiting Redux Documentation directly?" So I can't use it right now :S All i wanted to do was changing the slides file so I can have the usual wp_editor instead of a plain textbox. Now my theme crashed >.< BTW Maybe you should add an option to choose the editor for slides OR to add addtional fields. Thanks! But it's a real stunning plugin

Comment: @Dovy the generator seems not working. Zip file is damaged

Comment: Put an issue on our tracker and we'll get on it.  :)

Answer (score 2):

**Try These Steps hope that helps**

**Step 1**
: [Download Redux framework](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework)

**Step 2**: Extract / Unzip downloaded redux framework files.

**Step 3**: Copy **ReduxCore** folder from extracted / unzip files into your active theme directory.

**Step 4**: Create New folder in your current active theme directory called **functions**

**Step 5**: Copy downloaded framework file sample-config.php from **sample directory** into your theme **functions folder**

**Step 6**: Rename this copied file from sample-config.php to admin-config.php

**Step 7**: Copy paste this code in bottom of your functions.php file.

```
if( !class_exists('ReduxFramework')){
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/ReduxCore/Framework.php');
}

if( !isset( $redux_demo ) ){
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__) . '/functions/admin-config.php');
}
```

**Step 8**: That's it. Now you can see theme options in your theme.
further you can customize your **/functions/admin-config.php** file based on your requirements.

[Reference link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxptU6K9XSo&index=1&list=PLHgkhCziFKlm3QelOgsrR1RS5yjovH01f)

Answer (score 1):

For my works:

```
    // load the theme's framework
if ( !class_exists( 'ReduxFramework' ) && file_exists( dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/ReduxCore/framework.php' ) ) {
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/ReduxCore/framework.php' );
}

// load the theme's options 
if ( !isset( $redux_owd ) && file_exists( dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/sample/sample-config.php' ) ) {
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/sample/sample-config.php' );
}
```

I have folder framework end in him i have ReduxCore end sample folder...check the code...
[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0):

use this in functions.php

```
// this will deactive demo mode of reduxframework plugin and will not display and addvertisement

if ( ! function_exists( 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' ) ) {
        function redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin( $redux ) {
            if ( $redux->args['opt_name'] != 'redux_demo' ) {
                $redux->args['dev_mode'] = false;
            }
        }

        add_action( 'redux/construct', 'redux_disable_dev_mode_plugin' );
    }

// add sample config to overwrite reduxcore/framework.php

if (!isset($redux_demo)){
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/sample-config.php');
}
```

To install the reduxframework plugin you will need tgm plugin

you will get tgm plugin from here --> http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

include tgm plugin in your theme function or copy and past tgm-init.php code in functions.php , don't forget about class-tgm-plugin-activation.php .

Example --> install redux framework plugin

```
$plugins = array( // add below code to add redux framework plugin

        array(
            'name'               => 'Redux Framework', // The plugin name.
            'slug'               => 'redux-framework-master', // The plugin slug (typically the folder name).
            'required'           => true, // If false, the plugin is only 'recommended' instead of required.
            'external_url'       => 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework', // If set, overrides default API URL and points to an external URL.
            'source'             => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/redux-framework-master.zip',
            'force_activation'   => true,
            'force_deactivation' => true,       
        ),
);
```

force_activation--> true , will active reduxframework when your theme will active .

'force_deactivation' => true, will deactive reduxframework when your theme will deactive .

you can add reduxframework in theme folder , but when you will check theme by wordpress theme check you will get many error .

I already developed a theme , download and check it it will help you a lot.
http://www.nxcreation.com/alpha-nx-one/

Answer (score 0):

In that link http://tgmpluginactivation.com/download/ generate plugin activation file ("class-tgm-plugin-activation.php" include the file into your theme folder) download zip file

In that file "Array of plugin arrays"

add the code

```
// add below code to add redux framework plugin

$plugins = array( 
    array(
        'name'               => 'Redux Framework', // The plugin name.
        'slug'               => 'redux-framework', // The plugin slug (typically the folder name).
        'required'           => false, 
        'version'           => '3.6.1',
        'external_url'       => 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework', 
        'source'             => 'repo', 
        'force_activation'   => false,
        'force_deactivation' => false,       
    ),
);
```

In this use for plugin path

'source'             => 'repo',

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to include redux framework in wordpress theme.

```
    // Including Redux Framework
    require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/redux/redux-framework.php');
    if ( class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
        require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/redux/sample/barebones-config.php');
    }
```